# Why can't I use anything but (0 and 1) when I specify the radix in a literal?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

```
y <= a when (s = b"--0") else '0' -- Erroneous.
y <= a when (s = "--0")  else '0' -- Okay.
```

I'm using Vivado and it gives me the error `Error: '-' is not a valid character in b"--0"` only if I type the radix in front of the literal. It does the same with `Z`, `U`, `X`, `L`, `W`, and `H`.

Note that this works fine when I use `VHDL 2008` and I already use it but I wanted to know why is this the behaviour in `VHDL`.

My first thought is that `b"000"`, for example, is treated as a `BIT_VECTOR`, but I tried the following:

```
architecture behav of ent is
    signal bv: BIT_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0) := b"000";
begin
    y <= a when (s = bv); -- Erroneous.
end behav;
```

But this did not work. Vivado gave me an error that there's no `=` operator defined for those two types. So I think that b"000" is not implicitly a `BIT_VECTOR`.

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076-1993 13.7 Bit string literals. "If the base specifier is 'B', the extended digits in the bit value are restricted to 0 and 1." See 13.6 String literals where any graphic character is accepted. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.8 Bit string literals for the -2008 behavior

Comment: Section 13 (-1993) and Clause 15 (-2008) are entitled :Lexical elements. It doesn't seem likely you can be effective in a language without understanding it's lexical elements.